What is the difference between using (double) versus multiplying by 1.0 when type casting an integer to a double?
I was wondering what the difference is between converting an integer to a double using double versus multiplying the integer by 1.0
int a = 4
int b = 3

double c = 1.0 * a / b
double d = (double) a / b

ultimately both c and d output 1.333.. 
From what I understand c is converted to a double because 1.0 * a makes a a double, and when dividing using a float and an integer the output will always be a  float, but in a hypothetical situation where you just want to convert an integer to a double, what's the difference between the two methods?


I found two questions that ask similar things, but are either asked in such a strange way no one was able to answer op, or asked something slightly different.
1: Converting an int to a double by multiplying by 1.0 or adding 1d? (incomprehensible)
2: Cast with (double) or " *1.0 " (asked for best practices)

c is a double b/c you declared it to be.

Use the cast.  When writing code, correctness and maintainability are both important.  While both choices may give you the correct answer, only one is obviously "i want to cast an int to a double".  The other is "why is this number being multiplied by 1.0? this looks useless.  oh, it's an int, so this makes it a double", which is useless cognitive load that you impose on the future reader of the code (which might be you in 3 months wondering what 3 months younger you was thinking when they wrote that).

+1. It may also be a good idea to add parentheses -- maybe this is just me, but I never remember if (double) x / y means (double) (x / y) or ((double) x) / y. (In fact, I usually use 1.0 * x / y for exactly that reason, but I agree with you that the explicit cast is probably better!)

The 1.0 * x / y pattern is very common. patterns in this sense are jargon - to those foreign to the craft, they are impossible to understand. nevertheless, jargon makes communication between craftsfolk better, not worse: Because it's foreign, the odds that common usage in other contexts confuses matters is reduced. Same here: If you're a java coder and 1.0 * x / y throws you for a loop, I'm sorry, but, you're bad at it. That pattern is way to common not to recognize right off the bat, and it has the considerable advantage of avoiding precedence order confusion.

This 'answer' also doesn't actually answer the question: What is the difference? A good answer should probably include the term "Automatic widening conversion", indicate that the 1.0 * part will be in the class file, but that hotspot will eliminate it so it won't ever cause measurable performance loss. In that sense: It jumps to the conclusion too fast without explaining why, but the base conclusion is correct: There is no difference other than style.

@rzwitserloot i'm glad you think it's common.  i've been a java programmer for over 20 years at various companies and active in open source, and i've never seen that used before i stumbled across this question.  so i respectfully disagree with your assertion that it is any sort of "standard" practice.
